# Automatic arrows to show movement of a vector with respect to standard basis vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I have the look of what I want but there should be an easier way. I was thinking of a \foreach to make the repeated arrows but maybe there's a way to define a \draw (a) -- (b) that would automatically place in arrows between vertices of a polygonal path?

It would also be great if this would work in 3D.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick, lightgray]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[->] (1,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[->] (2,0) -- (2,1);
    \draw[->] (2,1) -- (2,2);
    \draw[->] (2,2) -- (2,3);
    \draw[->][purple][->] (0,0) -- (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could maybe look at the `decoration` library of `TikZ`. It allows you to put arrow tips (among other things) spaced with a given distance along a given path. This way, you wouldn't have to draw multiple arrows pointing in the same direction.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I can't seem to get it to work with "decoration={markings, mark= between positions 0 and 2 step 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}}" and "postaction={decorate}" since the spacing is relative to how long the vector is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `\pic` (first) approach. I made a `\pic` that draws the components ordered x,y,z and then the vector. A caveat: only works with integer coordinates. This is the 3d version, but I think it's easy to modify for a 2d version.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\tikzset
{%
   pics/vector basis/.style n args={3}{code=%
   {% x component
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\myabs{abs(#1)}
      \ifnum\myabs>0
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\mysgn{\myabs/#1}
        \foreach\i in {1,...,\myabs}
          \draw[-latex,gray] ({\mysgn*(\i-1)},0,0) --++ (\mysgn,0,0);
      \fi
    % y component
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\myabs{abs(#2)}
      \ifnum\myabs>0
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\mysgn{\myabs/#2}
        \foreach\i in {1,...,\myabs}
          \draw[-latex,gray] (#1,{\mysgn*(\i-1)},0) --++ (0,\mysgn,0);
      \fi
    % z component
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\myabs{abs(#3)}
      \ifnum\myabs>0
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\mysgn{\myabs/#3}
        \foreach\i in {1,...,\myabs}
          \draw[-latex,gray] (#1,#2,{\mysgn*(\i-1)}) --++ (0,0,\mysgn);
      \fi
    % vector
      \draw[-latex,pic actions] (0,0,0) -- (#1,#2,#3);
   }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={120}{20}]
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[left]  {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[right] {$y$};
\draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {$z$};
\pic[red]  {vector basis={-2}{0}{3}};
\pic[blue] {vector basis={1}{2}{3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to adapt it to keep it into my visual style and it works. Thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome!! :-)